# In the video, "Inner Life of a Cell", what's the empty space between the molecules?

Tags: cell-biology

In the video, ["Inner Life of a Cell"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_zD3NxSsD8) there's a lot of empty space between the proteins. Is it just a simplification (i.e. they omit smaller molecules)? If so, what are the smaller molecules supposed to be? Or is it just a vacuum small enough to be ignored?

I've done some reading up on it, and found that it's called cytosol which is a complicated mixture of random proteins and molecules.

Comment: It is a vast oversimplification. At a minimum the space between proteins will be mostly water. There will be plenty of small molecules, ions, and dissolved gases as well. Also, the [cytosol is a pretty crowded place.](http://www.nature.com/nchembio/journal/v7/n6/images_article/nchembio.575-F1.jpg). Also, it might be helpful if you linked to the video so we can see what you're talking about more easily.

Comment: @Loogai you answer the question in your question: "I've done some reading up on it, and found that it's called cytosol which is a complicated mixture of random proteins and molecules." - therefore, it's unclear to me why you've posted this as a question, and unclear what question remains.

Comment: I was seeking clarification for the cytosol answer and if the proteins in the video comprise the cytosol, if so the space between them is vacuum. I thought I implied it but I wasn't clear enough. Sorry. Also: "what are the smaller molecules supposed to be?"

Comment: If the video were realistic and showed all the molecules in the cell, you couldn't see anything because water would always get in the way.

Comment: It could be plasma containing water.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common simplification of videos and textbook illustrations. In reality a cell is much more crowded and there is hardly any space between proteins. You can find a [more realistic drawing here](http://mgl.scripps.edu/people/goodsell/illustration/public) (I linked the pictures, because I am not sure about the license).

Regarding the cytosol:
Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytosol):

> The cytosol or cytoplasmic matrix is the liquid found inside cells.
>   
> [...]
>   Most of the cytosol is water, which makes up about 70% of the total volume of a typical cell
>   
> [...]
>   The amount of protein in cells is extremely high, and approaches 200 mg/ml, occupying about 20-30% of the volume of the cytosol